# I have problems with WPDB Syntaxis

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have problems with this code, it appears the syntaxis is wrong but i don't know where is the mistake:

```
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("
  INSERT INTO
    $wpdb->wp_consultte(Imagen,Paterno,Materno,Nombre,Lugar,Fecha,Genero,EstadoCivil,Domicilio,Colonia,Postal,Ciudad,TelCasa,Movil,Nextel,NextelKey,Email,Email2,Email3,Otro,Facebook,Twitter,Blackberry,Linkedin,Carrera,Universidad,Titulo,Egreso,UniLugar,Maximo,OtrosCursos,Idioma1,Hablado1,Escrito1,Idioma2,Hablado2,Escrito2,Idioma3,Hablado3,Escrito3,TipoE1,NombreE1,DomE1,SectorE1,JefeE1,TelE1,RespE1,ActE1,TipoE1,NombreE2,DomE2,SectorE2,JefeE2,TelE2,RespE2,ActE2,NombreE3,DomE3,SectorE3,JefeE3,TelE3,RespE3,ActE3,OPC,OPD,OSP,Comisiones,Regulaciones,Programas,Regimenes,Ordenamiento,Negociadores)
  VALUES
    ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')
  ",
  $destino,$paterno,$materno,$nombre,$estado,$datepicker,$genero,$civil,$domicilio,$colonia,$cp,$ciudad,$telefono,$movil,$nextel,$nextelkey,$email,$email2,$email3,$skype,$facebook,$twitter,$blackberry,$linkedin,$carrera,$universidad,$titulo,$egreso,$uniestado,$maximo,$seminarios,$idioma,$hablado,$escrito,$idioma2,$hablado2,$escrito2,$idioma3,$hablado3,$escrito3,$tipos,$empresa,$domempresa,$secempresa,$jefe,$contactos,$resposabilidades,$actividades,$tipos,$empresa2,$domempresa2,$secempresa2,$jefe2,$contactos2,$resposabilidades2,$actividades2,$empresa3,$domempresa3,$secempresa3,$jefe3,$contactos3,$resposabilidades3,$actividades3,$opc,$opd,$osp,$com,$rra,$pfe,$rea,$ole,$nin,$log
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the query like this? values(%s,%s,%s...)
without using the quotes? ie: from this: '%s', to %s,%s....

also try setting your table name before including it within the main query

```
$table_consultte = $wpdb->prefix."consultte"; //(I assume the prefix is 'wp_')
```

you could also try something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table_consultte." (Imagen,Paterno,Materno,Nombre,Lugar,Fecha,Genero,EstadoCivil,Domicilio,Colonia,Postal,Ciudad,TelCasa,Movil,Nextel,NextelKey,Email,Email2,Email3,Otro,Facebook,Twitter,Blackberry,Linkedin,Carrera,Universidad,Titulo,Egreso,UniLugar,Maximo,OtrosCursos,Idioma1,Hablado1,Escrito1,Idioma2,Hablado2,Escrito2,Idioma3,Hablado3,Escrito3,TipoE1,NombreE1,DomE1,SectorE1,JefeE1,TelE1,RespE1,ActE1,TipoE1,NombreE2,DomE2,SectorE2,JefeE2,TelE2,RespE2,ActE2,NombreE3,DomE3,SectorE3,JefeE3,TelE3,RespE3,ActE3,OPC,OPD,OSP,Comisiones,Regulaciones,Programas,Regimenes,Ordenamiento,Negociadores) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s - add the rest! )";

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( $strQuery, $destino,$paterno,$materno,$nombre,$estado,$datepicker,$genero,$civil,$domicilio,$colonia,$cp,$ciudad,$telefono,$movil,$nextel,$nextelkey,$email,$email2,$email3,$skype,$facebook,$twitter,$blackberry,$linkedin,$carrera,$universidad,$titulo,$egreso,$uniestado,$maximo,$seminarios,$idioma,$hablado,$escrito,$idioma2,$hablado2,$escrito2,$idioma3,$hablado3,$escrito3,$tipos,$empresa,$domempresa,$secempresa,$jefe,$contactos,$resposabilidades,$actividades,$tipos,$empresa2,$domempresa2,$secempresa2,$jefe2,$contactos2,$resposabilidades2,$actividades2,$empresa3,$domempresa3,$secempresa3,$jefe3,$contactos3,$resposabilidades3,$actividades3,$opc,$opd,$osp,$com,$rra,$pfe,$rea,$ole,$nin,$log));
```

then use:

```
<?php $wpdb->show_errors(); ?>
```

to see if it produces any errors..

Marty